# JavaScriptSerializer not working

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have some code that serializes an object to JSON

```
   Tweets t = new Tweets();
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(t);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\JSON.txt", json);
```

However, the string `json` only outputs a null value (`{}`)

There's definitely values in the object and they all have getters and setters

Why would the Serializer only return blank objects?

EDIT

```
class Message
{
    public static string sender { get; set; }
    public static string body { get; set; }
    public static string Message_ID { get; set; }
    public static DateTime received { get; set; }
    public static string MessageHeader { get; set; }
    public static string bodyresult { get; set; }
}
```

Tweets inherits that, but has methods that are Tweet specific

Comment: What does your Tweets class look like?

Comment: Have you debugged this? Is `t` definitely not null?

Comment: All those properties are static -- they're shared across all instances of the class.  Thus they won't be serialized

Comment: @barrick definitely not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the Static from those Properties and Serialization will work for you.  By making those Properties all static you can only store 1 message.